# Gracefully handling expected BindingExpression errors

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a `ComboBox` bound to an `ObservableCollection` where the `DisplayMemberPath` references an object property `Url`.

My `CompositeCollection` contains a `null` item, allowing the user to have an optional selection:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotificationServer, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Url">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="comboBoxSource" Source="{Binding Path=NotificationServers}" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="None"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboBoxSource}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

This works fine (it produces a dropdown of URLs and a default "None" item), but while debugging, I have an error because the `Url` property is not available on the `null` item:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Url' property not found on 'object' ''ComboBoxItem' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Url; DataItem='ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

How do I gracefully handle this, even though it doesn't cause any runtime issues. It's probably just debugging noise, but a nuisance nonetheless.

Comment: `TargetNullValue` and `FallbackValue` are your friends.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your 'null' item should simply be an item in your collection (of the same type as the rest of the items) that has no properties set, or at least no properties that are displayed. That way, you can avoid the `Binding` errors all together, because your 'null' item *will* have a `Url` property to data bind to.

---

UPDATE >>>

You can set the 'null' item like this when you access your other data items:

```
NotificationServers.Add(new NotificationServer());
NotificationServers.AddRange(GetNotificationServers());
```

That will make it the first item. You could also do something like this:

```
NotificationServers.Add(new NotificationServer() { DisplayedProperty = "Please Select" });
```

Comment: Won't work, because my `SelectedNotificationServer` property needs to be null if "None" is selected.

Comment: There's always a way... just check for the 'null' object in the `SelectedNotificationServer` property setter and set the value to `null` if found. Simple.

Comment: So this will require me to always prepend a dummy item to my ObservableCollection. Where would I do that? My ViewModel ctor where I set the DataContext?